# change visa type in visa application form

Tags: visas, uk

I mistakenly opted for short term student visa when I am supposed to opt for visitor visa.

can I change it now?[image: visa]

Answer (score 1):

The general guidelines, for both types of visas, **do not contain** any information on how to switch from an **incorrectly** applied visa type to another.

So either contact them directly or **withdrawal** the incorrect application and the apply for the **correct** visa.

Assume that the fee for the present application will not be refunded, since the processing has already been started.

Comment: Payment comes later in the process than this. So it should be fine to just abandon the application and start over.